# Function will not call correctly, C

Tags: arrays, c

I am a beginner and am doing pretty bad in my class right now, I just can't get some of this stuff down. I am working on one of the final homeworks and can't figure out the problem with my code. It's probably really messy but the main thing I'm having trouble with right now is the getArea function. It won't run correctly when I call it and says 'expected expression before int'. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

```c
//This program takes 18 numbers and puts it in a single dimensional array and a two dimensional array.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define COLMAX 3
#define ROWMAX 6

double triArea(double a, double b, double c);
double checkValidation(double a, double b, double c);
double func1(double values[][COLMAX], int);
 int main(void)
 {
     unsigned int seed;
     double tArea = 0.0;
     int rand_int();
     int loop;
     int col;
     int row;
     int counter = 0;

     srand(time(NULL));
     int RandomArray[18];
     int ArrayTwo[6][3];
     printf("\nOne dimensional array\n");

     for(loop = 0; loop < 18; loop++)
     {
         RandomArray[loop] = rand_int();
         printf("%d ", RandomArray[loop]);
     }

     printf("\nTwo dimensional array\n");
     for(row = 0; row < ROWMAX; row++)
     {
         for(col = 0; col < COLMAX; col++)
         {
             ArrayTwo[row][col] = RandomArray[counter];
             counter++;
             //int total = 0;
             //total = total + array2[row][col];
             printf("%d\t", ArrayTwo[row][col]);
             getArea(ArrayTwo[row][col]);
             //printf("The total is %d", total);
         }
         printf("\n");
     }
     printf("\n");
     double total = 0.0;
     double ArrayTwoTotal[ROWMAX][COLMAX];
     total = func1(ArrayTwoTotal, ROWMAX);
     printf("total is %.2lf \n", total);
     system ("PAUSE");
     return 0;
 }

double checkValidation(double a, double b, double c)
//triangleValueA + triangleValueB >= triangleValueC) && (triangleValueB + triangleValueC >= triangleValueA) && (triangleValueA + triangleValueC >= triangleValueB
{
    int count = 0;
    //a = base, b = height, c = area
    if ((a + b >= c) && (b + c >= a) && (a + c >= b))
    {

    }
}

//Calculate area of a triangle
double getArea(int[int][int])
{
    double base, height, area;
    area = base*height/2.0;
    printf("The area is %.lf\n", area);
    checkValidation(base, height, area);
    return area;
}

//Function to get the totals of the 1 dimensional array
double func1(double ArrayTwoTotal[][COLMAX], int rows)
{
  double sum = 0.0;
  int i, j;
  for(i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0 ; j < COLMAX ; j++)
    {
      sum += ArrayTwoTotal[i][j];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

 //Function to find a random number
 int rand_int()
{
    int x = 0;
    x = ((rand() % 100)+1);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: You have prototypes for all other functions, but not this one. Add the prototype above the main function. Voting to close this as typo.

Comment: the same issue persists even after adding at the top:
double getArea(int ArrayTwo[int][int]);

Comment: Oh, I looked to quickly. What is `[int][int]` supposed to mean? That makes no sense. You should minimize all this code. It's way more than necessary to demonstrate the problem. Create a [mre]

Comment: I put ```[int][int]``` on accident, it should just be ```[int]```. It is meant to get the values in the row of the array. I need to make 6 triangles (one for each row) and the getArea function is to get those. I also did try restarting the code earlier on, but it just made things worst and I ended up losing my progress than I gained. Sorry, I'm just so new to this and the professor is really stingy about the code being in a certain order vs. the output solely

Comment: It still does not make sense to put the word `int` there. Are you just guessing the syntax? You should probably google "c pass arrays to functions" or something like that.

Comment: I am not, I am using the example the professor gave us which executes fine, but mine won't, which is why I came here. I will look into it further on my own though. Thanks.

Comment: seems to be little point calling the function anyway, since you don't use the value it returns

Comment: In that case it seems like your professor is guessing the syntax ;)

Comment: Because `double getArea(int[int])` is simply not valid C.

Comment: @Darius_C02 With `double base, height, area; area = base*height/2.0;`, what do you think is the value of `base` and `height` when passed to the multiplication?

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of things that you need to look at.
First getArea() function doesn't have any declaration. Please declare it first and in a correct way.